How to slice a 3D cylinder in MATLAB?
I'm trying to create a function that plots a cylinder with slices at a given angle  where:

l - length of a cylinder
d - diameter
a - angle
n - number of slices

Here is what I have so far:
function baguett(l, d, a, n)
  r = d/2;
  [X,Y,Z] = cylinder(r);
  Z = Z*l;
  obj = surf(Z,Y,X);
  hold on
  patch(Z(1,:), Y(1,:), X(1,:), Z(1,:))
  patch(Z(end,:), Y(end,:), X(end,:), Z(end,:))
  axis equal

  [x,y,z] = meshgrid(-l:.2:l,-l:.25:l,-l:.16:l);
  v = x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2-z.^2);
  xslice = [1];
  yslice = [];
  zslice = [];
  slice(x,y,z,v,xslice,yslice,zslice);

It returns this plot:

However what I would like to get is something like this (for 90 angle I guess):

Could somebody please help?

what you want is to plot3 the circles ("slices") around your cylinder

@Thales could you please explain how can I do this?  I need to actually slice my cyllinder and be able to plot them seperately after that.

If you need control over individual slices, as you seem to indicate in your comment, my recommendation would be:

instead of generating a long cylinder and trying to slice it arbitrarily, just build your slices individually then stack them all together to create your long cylinder. This way you retain graphic handles for the base slices and you can still use the graphic handle for further modifications.

It goes like this:
%% Initial model cylinder
% Generate a model cylinder, unitary length, assigned radius
D = 5 ; R = D/2;
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(R);

%% Now work out how many copies you need
L = 12 ;   % Total length of stacked cylinders
n = 9 ;     % Number of base cylinders/slices to stack

Lu = L / n ;    % Length of a base cylinder/slice
Z = Z * Lu ;    % Scale base cylinder

%% and stack them up

colCyl = [.8 .8 .8] ;   % light grey
colEnds = [.7 .7 .7] ;  % darker gray

hold on
% we run the loop in reverse (from n to 1) to let MATLAB automatically
% preallocate the graphic handle arrays (without complaining)
for k=n:-1:1
    % Generate the "Zc" coordinate for each base cylinder
    Zc = Z + (k-1)*Lu ;
    % generate base cylinder, with its end caps, and group graphic handles
    % into one hg object
    hg(k) = hggroup ;
    hs(k) = surf(Zc,X,Y, 'FaceColor',colCyl, 'EdgeColor','none','Parent',hg(k)) ;
    hp(2,n) = patch( Zc(end,:), Y(1,:), X(1,:), Zc(end,:) , 'FaceColor',colEnds, 'Parent',hg(k) ) ;
    hp(1,n) = patch( Zc(1,:)  , Y(1,:), X(1,:), Zc(1,:)   , 'FaceColor',colEnds, 'Parent',hg(k) ) ;
end
axis equal ; view(-10,40) ; grid on

This will produce 9 cylinder slices, stacked together to form a cylinder with length L:

Now each of your hggroup contains the graphic handle of a base cylinder/slice (s surf object) and its two end caps (2x patch objects). These hggroup are useful to change properties to all the graphic object contained, and even more convenient if you need transformations (rotations or translations).

A few example of individual slice manipulations:
%% Now each cylinder can be acted on its own by operating on its hggroup
% ex1: translate the middle cylinder (#5) upward

hax = gca ;
t1 = hgtransform('Parent',hax);
Tz = makehgtform('translate',[0 0 2]);

set( hg(5), 'Parent',t1) ;
set(t1,'Matrix',Tz) ;

will move the middle slice slightly upward:


%% ex2: make every second slice invisible:
for k=2:2:n
    set(hg(k),'Visible','off')
end



%% ex3: change color of one specific slice
set(hg(3).Children,'FaceColor','r')


